# Running Internet Explorer on Linux

Tags: windows, wine, ie

I am running a DVR which requires ActiveX plugin on IE to view the video streaming so I need advice with how to run Internet Explorer, as the installation advice I've found so far is old and hasn't worked.  I tried newest and older versions, running it through Wine, but got an error message about not having the right version of Windows installed (I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS).  Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't be running IE in Windows let alone with Wine. IE has been deprecated along time ago.

Comment: I think you have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/1081494). If you tell us _why_ you want to run IE on Ubuntu, or what you are trying to do, we might be able to help you.

Comment: @cocomac Thanks, I am running a DVR which requires ActiveX plugin on IE to view the video streaming.

Comment: so you need an active x plugin to play the DVR,this does not mean you need to install internet explorer on your system,please tell what active x plugin you need and the comunity will most likely be able to solve it for you.

Comment: @trondhansen Yes, however my understanding was that ActiveX is IE/Microsoft specific.  Thanks.

Comment: Both Firefox and chrome have extensions that mirror ActiveX - if you look that up (various hits come up if you Google it), it may well work better than trying to run IE or edge through wine.